# How to avoid execution of unused dataProvider methods?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

If I need to run only one test from class like

```
phpunit --filter someTest tests/ExampleTest.php
```

PHPUnit still initializes dataProviders for all tests in that class, which, in my case, takes plenty of time.
Is there a way to initialize dataProvider only for executed method?

Comment: Could you not simply break the tests into different files, so then you do not need to initialize all the data providers?

Comment: It's not the variant. I just write one big test file for one module. And after writing test I run it. When there became lots of tests data initialization takes really a while, and when i add test I actually need to check only this test and initialize dataProvider only for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `--group` instead of `--filter`, only the tests of the selected group are initialized. That should also apply to data providers.

To do so, you have to add the `@group` annotation (fortunately this is possible per method and not only per class). If you still want to be able to execute all tests separately, put each one in its own group:

```
/**
 * @test
 * @group someTest
 * @dataProvider someData
 */
public function someTest(...)
```